# How to get count of all active users/sessions, those are looking same offer page in Sitecore CDP

Tags: cdp

I am working on a scenario in Sitecore CDP, "How to get a count of all active users/sessions, those are looking same offer page".

Any steps or pointer will be good to explore.

Thanks

Comment: no way to do it without 3rd parties

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the statement above, I have identified the following steps that I could take to address this issue.

1. **Set up Event Tracking:** Ensure that Sitecore CDP is configured to track events or interactions on your website, including when users visit the offer page. Depending on your CDP setup, you may need to define custom events or utilize built-in events.
2. **Create a Segment:** Define a segment that includes users who have interacted with the specific offer page. This segment should be based on the events or criteria that you've set up in Step 1.
3. **Segment Query:** Use the Sitecore CDP interface to create a segment query. This query should filter for users who have interacted with the offer page during a specific time frame to capture "active" users.
4. **Retrieve User Count:** Once the segment query is created, you can run it to retrieve the count of active users who are currently looking at the same offer page. This count will give you the number of users with ongoing sessions on the offer page.

Hope this might help.

Comment: 1) The segment will update nightly so not all active sessions we can track
2) How can we used that Retrieve User Count to show this value in any experience or DM.

Comment: @Arun Could you please explain a bit more or update question with more details so that it is easy to understand bit more.

Comment: segments are not "real time"